# attach email with multiple pictures

Tags: android, email, attachment

I have problem when I wanna upload many pictures as attachment on email, I cannot attach pictures to the email also the extention is not recognized as JPEG (if I attach single picture, single picture was successfully). Here my source code :

```
// imgName is string variable with initialiation above.
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                                                                     

Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
email.setType("application/octet-stream");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "" });
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My Subject");
email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");


ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
for (int i=1;i<=6;i++)
{
    Bitmap i1 = null;
int imgID=getBaseContext().getResources().getIdentifier(imgName+"_"+String.valueOf(i), "drawable", getBaseContext().getPackageName());
if (imgID!=0) {
    i1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), imgID), 200, 200, false);                       
i1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
    String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

    File file = new File(extStorageDirectory,imgName+"_"+String.valueOf(i));                                                                        
    try {
    //file.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);                                  
    fos.write(bitmapdata);                                      
    fos.flush();
    fos.close();

    Uri u = Uri.fromFile(file);
        uris.add(u);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
email.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent emailIntent;
        emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "");
        // emailIntent.setType("application/zip");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                getString(R.string.ixpenseRecord));
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                "Images attach...");
        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        for (String  filepath: arrlistImages) {
            File file = new File(filepath);
            Uri csvURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
            uris.add(csvURI);
        }
        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        emailIntent.setType("text/html");
        try {
            CommonMethods.openGmailAppIntent(this, emailIntent);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

//the other method to open gmail app is code below:

```
public static void openGmailAppIntent(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
        final List<ResolveInfo> matches = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        ResolveInfo best = null;
        for (final ResolveInfo info : matches)
            if (info.activityInfo.packageName.endsWith(".gm")
                    || info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains("gmail"))
                best = info;
        if (best != null)
            intent.setClassName(best.activityInfo.packageName,
                    best.activityInfo.name);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        // startActivity(Intent
        // .createChooser(emailIntent, "Email to Send"));
        try {

            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            CommonMethods.showMessageForValiDation(context,
                    CommonVariable.VALIDATION_NO_GMAIL_APP,
                    CommonVariable.iXPENSE_APP_FOLDER);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

In the main code, arrlistImages is the arralist of string that will be get all images path...and then put this code in your main activity.

I hope its useful to you.